# Iterating through attribute in layer to create new layers

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, loop, iteration

I am working on the school project in QGIS, in which I have Price map of the buildings in a vector layer. Each polygon has its price attribute. The maximal value of price is 20 000.

I would like to decompose the layer and create new selection (and layers as well) where would I have only buildings in specific range of prices. It would start [0;1000), [1000;2000) up to 20 000.

I was trying to loop in the "Select by Expression", however I was not successful so far.

Comment: Are you using PyQGIS to try and do the iteration?

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is the aim of the school project to learn about coding and expressions? Or to produce the content output as a map? its possible you are using a sledgehammer to solve a problem which a simple style category could solve. If you could update your question a bit more, that would help heaps.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there is a point layer `'random_point_test'` with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Create a `"class"` attribute that will brake `"value"`s into ranges

In the "Field Calculator" the following expression was used:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "value" > 0 AND "value" <= 33 THEN 1
    WHEN "value" > 33 AND "value" <= 66 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END
```

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Split vector layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) to split features based on the `"class"` attribute as *'Unique ID field'* and get the final output

[image: output]

So, in the end there will be three groups of points, based on `"class"` attribute.